# Play Audio Track Asynchronously

Tags: android, dot42

I've tried to use Xamarin example of audio record/play using the follow code:
[Example_WorkingWithAudio](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/Example_WorkingWithAudio)

At the following `Task` i have `async` error:

```
protected async Task PlayAudioTrackAsync ()
{
    audioTrack = new AudioTrack (
        // Stream type
        Android.Media.Stream.Music,
        // Frequency
        11025,
        // Mono or stereo
        ChannelConfiguration.Mono,
        // Audio encoding
        Android.Media.Encoding.Pcm16bit,
        // Length of the audio clip.
        buffer.Length,
        // Mode. Stream or static.
        AudioTrackMode.Stream);

    audioTrack.Play ();

    await audioTrack.WriteAsync (buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

Changed for dot42:

```
protected async Task PlayAudioTrackAsync()
{
    audioTrack = new AudioTrack (AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,11025,
                                 AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                                 AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                                 buffer.Length,
                                 AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM
                                 );
    audioTrack.Play ();
    await audioTrack.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

How do i change "audioTrack.WriteAsync" ? I've compiler error on this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AudioTrack does not have a WriteAsync. For dot42, use this line:

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew( () => audioTrack.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) );
```

I assume this works for Xamarin as well.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from that answer i also used audioTrack.WriteAsync() method to play audio async. I think need not create an async method.Here is what playing audio asynchronously.

```
public void audioTrackPlay(byte[] audioBuffer){try {

     audioTrack.Play();
   //  audioTrack.Write(audioBuffer, 0, audioBuffer.Length);
    audioTrack.WriteAsync(audioBuffer, 0, audioBuffer.Length);

     Toast.MakeText(this,"Server Started",ToastLength.Short).Show();
   } catch (Exception e) { }   }
```